# How to remove dictionary values based on conditions of sudoku removes wrong values?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, sudoku

I have a function for solving sudoku that updates my dictionary of key=coordinates; value = possible digits based on if a digit "k" is already in a row on the sudoku board:

```
k = 8
for key, value in dic_i.items():
    if k in solving[key[0],0:]:
        if k in value:
            value.remove(k)
print(dic_i)
```

I have pasted the partially solved sudoku board and my initial possibilities dictionary here:

```
solving = np.array([3, 1, 9, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 5],
                   [4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 8, 9, 7, 1],
                   [0, 0, 6, 9, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3],
                   [0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 0, *8, 5, 0],
                   [2, 6, 1, 5, 8, 9, 3, 4, 7],
                   [0, 3, 5, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0],
                   [6, 2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 5, 1, 8],
                   [1, 9, 8, 2, 6, 5, 7, 3, 4]])
dic_i
Out[1081]: 
{(2, 0): [7, 8],
 (2, 1): [7, 8],
 (3, 0): [7, 8, 9],
 (3, 1): [7, 8],
 (3, 5): [3, 6, 9],
 (3, 8): [6, 9],
 (5, 0): [8, 9],
 (5, 5): [6, 9],
 (5, 6): [1, 8],
 (5, 7): [6, 9],
 (5, 8): [2, 6, 9],
 (6, 7): [6, 9],
 (6, 8): [6, 9]}
```

I'm focusing on removing the possible digit "8" from row 4, after running my code at the top, I get:

```
dic_i
Out[1080]: 
{(2, 0): [7, 8],
 (2, 1): [7],
 (3, 0): [7, 9],
 (3, 1): [7],
 (3, 5): [3, 6, 9],
 (3, 8): [6, 9],
 (5, 0): [8, 9],
 (5, 5): [6, 9],
 (5, 6): [1, 8],
 (5, 7): [6, 9],
 (5, 8): [2, 6, 9],
 (6, 7): [6, 9],
 (6, 8): [6, 9]}
```

I can't seem to figure out how for (2,1) - the digit 8 is removed??? there is no digit 8 in row 3... (for (3,0) and (3,1) it correctly removed digit 8).

Answer (score -1):

It works when I run it.

```
import numpy as np
solving = np.array([[3, 1, 9, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 5],
                   [4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 8, 9, 7, 1],
                   [0, 0, 6, 9, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3],
                   [0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 8, 5, 0],
                   [2, 6, 1, 5, 8, 9, 3, 4, 7],
                   [0, 3, 5, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0],
                   [6, 2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 5, 1, 8],
                   [1, 9, 8, 2, 6, 5, 7, 3, 4]])

dic_i = {(2, 0): [7, 8],
 (2, 1): [7, 8],
 (3, 0): [7, 8, 9],
 (3, 1): [7, 8],
 (3, 5): [3, 6, 9],
 (3, 8): [6, 9],
 (5, 0): [8, 9],
 (5, 5): [6, 9],
 (5, 6): [1, 8],
 (5, 7): [6, 9],
 (5, 8): [2, 6, 9],
 (6, 7): [6, 9],
 (6, 8): [6, 9]}

k = 8
for key, value in dic_i.items():
    if k in solving[key[0],0:]:
        if k in value:
            value.remove(k)
print(dic_i)
```

prints:

```
{(2, 0): [7, 8],
(2, 1): [7, 8],
(3, 0): [7, 9],
(3, 1): [7],
(3, 5): [3, 6, 9],
(3, 8): [6, 9],
(5, 0): [8, 9],
(5, 5): [6, 9],
(5, 6): [1, 8],
(5, 7): [6, 9],
(5, 8): [2, 6, 9],
(6, 7): [6, 9],
(6, 8): [6, 9]}
```

Comment: this could have been a comment on the original post that it works as intended

Comment: @Kevin Wang, thanks for the reply bro, I finally figured out what was wrong, it was a function that I wrote and used to get to the board that I posted here that was the problem - I assigned (2,1)'s possibility to [7,8] using "dic[d] = hidden_pair"; when I changed that to "dic[d] = deepcopy(hidden_pair)" my possibilities dictionary was no longer messed up. But the code for everything is too long to post, but thanks again, testing using the actual output pointed me toward the right direction.